# Loopback configuration issues in Cloud 9 workspace

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, loopbackjs

I am facing issue in running two instances at the same of loopback in Cloud 9 workspace:

1) Composing model visually --> `slc arc`

2) Running the app -> `node .`

I am able to run these two separately but can't run them together. Please let me know if I missed something

P.S I got this message while installing loopback in C9 Workspace

> Native thread-sleep not available. This will result in much slower
>   performance, but it will still work. You should re-install spawn-sync
>   or upgrade to the lastest version of node if possible.

Comment: I deployed the same in AWS EC2 instance and it worked fine. The problem should be with Cloud9 instance around porting. I have tried using both 3000 and process.env.PORT as port

Comment: I've never used loopback but as you mentioned, you should use process.env.PORT (which actually will be 8080). Also use process.env.IP instead of localhost. Also note that ports 8081 and 8082 are available.